# EntityFramework - load only last child from collection (performance issue)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Here is my model:

```
public partial class auctions
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<auction_data> auction_data { get; set; }
}
public partial class auction_data
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int auction_id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public virtual auctions auctions { get; set; }
}
```

Each auction may have thousands od auction_data items attached to it.
But i'm intrested only in the last of it:

```
var matchingAuctions = context.auctions.Where(a => /** some conditions **/);
foreach (auctions auction in matchingAuctions)
{
    var data = auction.auction_data.LastOrDefault(); // <---- takes very long time and memory when having large count of auction_data
}
```

It seems like EF loads all of auction_data into the memory and then returns the last one.
The question is: how can I improve performance of this code and avoid loading all these records into memory?

**EDIT: some timing**

```
DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now;
var data = auction.auction_data.LastOrDefault();
DateTime t2 = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan diff = t2 - t1; // 8.8s


DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now;
var data = auction.auction_data.OrderByDescending(a => a.id).FirstOrDefault();
DateTime t2 = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan diff = t2 - t1; // 8.7s

DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now;
var data = auction.auction_data.Last();
DateTime t2 = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan diff = t2 - t1; // 8.7s

int id = auction.id;
DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now;
var data = context.auction_data.Where(d => d.auction_id == id).OrderByDescending(d => d.id).FirstOrDefault();
DateTime t2 = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan diff = t2 - t1; // 0.06s
```

Comment: You could reverse the sort and then take the `First()` instead of the `Last()`

Comment: Why would you ever take the last row when no ordering is applied? _Define...last?  (highest Id/latest datetime?)_

Comment: Also tried this way, but got the same result

Comment: I think not..`auction.auction_data.OrderByDescending(a => /** column name **/).FirstOrDefault()` won't retreive all rows...

Comment: the last element is the last one inserted to a table (it has highest ID)

Comment: You should never assume that the highest id is the last one inserted. But it will work..

Comment: One year passed and i dint't figured it out. I ended up with creating a view in my DB which is ordered as I wish by default.

Answer (score 2):

It is normal. When you write `auction.auction_data` it reads all the auction.auction_data. If i was you i would do this to better performance:

```
public partial class auctions
{
  public int id { get; set; }
  public int lastDataId { get; set;}
  public virtual ICollection<auction_data> auction_data { get; set; }
}
```

and when inserting data insert the id as the last one.

**As a test:** I do not have a large database to test, But maybe changeing the `Last()` instead of `LastOrDefault()` can halp you. I read this:

*LastOrDefault is a helpful method. It finds the last element in a collection that matches a condition*

so to test for maching to condition it need to read all of the records, But **maybe** Last() doesn't

Comment: I did not believe in `OrderByDescending` from first. It is nearly the same thing. But the last (good) way is what i suggested, You need to have data id. ?

Comment: One thing else: `var data = context.auction_data.Where(d => d.auction_id == id).OrderByDescending(d => d.id).FirstOrDefault();` does not need **Sorting** It is only one element when id is primary key

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
var data = auction.auction_data.LastOrDefault();
```

to:

```
var data = auction.auction_data.OrderByDescending(x => x.id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I tried this way, but it almost makes no difference (in my test case 8.8 seconds vs 8.7 seconds)

Comment: Do you have proper indexes in place? I wonder, because EF does perform pretty well when your DB tables are indexed correctly.

Comment: yes, i have primary key set on ID. As i mentioned, the issue is EF reads entire table into memory and then returns record instead of reading only one row from table